# Multiplying error: * was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I recently got a problem. I am making a game module in batch and I got a strange error:

> Multiplying error "*!Map_PlayerLengthX! was unexpected at this time"

This is the whole code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pause >nul
cls
call :Map_DefinePlayer 4 2 loloolol
echo %Px1y1%%Px2y1%%Px3y1%%Px4y1%
echo %Px1y2%%Px2y2%%Px3y2%%Px4y2%
pause >nul

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Map v0.10 By KKZiomek ::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Map_Init
set Map_Running=1
goto :eof
:Map_Load
if !Map_Running!==0 goto :eof
set Map_Load_FileToLoad=%~1
set Map_Load_BorderX=%~2
set Map_Load_BorderY=%~3
set Map_Load_BChar=%~4
set Map_Load_LineTotal=0
for /f "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%l in (!Map_Load_FileToLoad!) do (
    set /a Map_Load_LineTotal+=1
    set Map_Line!Map_Load_LineTotal!=%%l
)
:Map_Load_ApplyCoords
for /l %%g in (1,1,!Map_Load_LineTotal!) do (
    call :Map_Load_StrLen Map_Line%%g Map_Line%%g_Len
    set /a Map_Load_ApplyCoords_DecidedLen+=!Map_Line%%g_Len!
)
set /a Map_Load_ApplyCoords_DecidedLen/=!Map_Load_LineTotal!
for /l %%y in (1,1,!Map_Load_LineTotal!) do (
    for /l %%x in (1,1,!Map_Load_ApplyCoords_DecidedLen!) do (
        set x%%xy%%y=!Map_Line%%y:~%%x,1!
    )
)
goto :eof
:Map_Load_StrLen
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set Map_Load_StrLen_Len=0
if defined %~1 for /f "delims=:" %%n in (
  '"(cmd /v:on /c echo(!%~1!&echo()|findstr /o ^^"'
) do set /a "Map_Load_StrLen_Len=%%n-3"
endlocal & if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%Map_Load_StrLen_Len%) else echo %Map_Load_StrLen_Len%
exit /b
:Map_Display
cls
for /l %%y in (1,1,!Map_Load_LineTotal!) do (
    set Map_Display_Line%%y=
    for /l %%x in (1,1,!Map_Load_ApplyCoords_DecidedLen!) do (
        set Map_Display_Line%%y=!Map_Display_Line%%y!!x%%xy%%y!
    )
)
for /l %%z in (1,1,!Map_Load_LineTotal!) do (
    echo !Map_Display_Line%%z!
)
goto :eof
:Map_ReloadPos
set XPos=%~1
set YPos=%~2
set x!XPos!y!YPos!=!Map_Line%YPos%:~%XPos%,1!
goto :eof
:Map_DefinePlayer
set Map_PlayerLengthX=%~1
set Map_PlayerWidthY=%~2
set Map_DefinePlayer_Scheme=%~3
set /a Map_DefinePlayer_Modifier=!Map_PlayerLengthX!-1
for /l %%p in (1,1,!Map_PlayerWidthY!) do (
    for /l %%q in (0,1,!Map_DefinePlayer_Modifier!) do (
        set /a localq=%%q+1
        set /a modq=%%q+((%%p-1)*!Map_PlayerLengthX!)
        set Px%localq%y%%p=!Map_DefinePlayer_Scheme:~%modq%,1!
    )
)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I get the error in the function `:Map_DefinePlayer`. I think it's mainly in this line: `set /a modq=%%q+((%%p-1)*!Map_PlayerLengthX!)`

Every function works fine instead of this function because of this weird multiplying error. I tried enbling delayed expansion again, changing `!Map_PlayerLengthX!` into `%Map_PlayerLengthX%` but then it only changed the error in `*4 was unexpected at this time`

Anyone has an idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
set /a "modq=%%q+((%%p-1)*!Map_PlayerLengthX!)"
```

the brackets in the expression are taken as closing brackets for the `FOR` loop